# How to extract numbers from rsync stats output

Tags: linux, bash, python, rsync

I am using rsync to back up a Raspberry Pi.  The rsync command runs inside a python script:

```
import os

os.system('sudo rsync -avzh --stats /etc /home /usr /mnt/BigMac/BigMac/PiBackups/PiZero')
```

The script runs fine and this is  an example of the output:

```
Number of files: 599,381 (reg: 468,108, dir: 83,703, link: 45,492, dev: 2,031, special: 47)
Number of created files: 18 (reg: 18)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 39
Total file size: 23.84G bytes
Total transferred file size: 58.12M bytes
Literal data: 58.12M bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 524.10K
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 18.37M
Total bytes received: 87.33K

sent 18.37M bytes  received 87.33K bytes  2.84M bytes/sec
total size is 23.84G  speedup is 1,291.70
```

I would like to extract two numerical values from this output.  Specifically, I would like to extract the numerical values from
**Total file size: 23.84G bytes** and
**Total bytes sent: 18.37M**

These two values will eventually be published to my MQTT broker later in the script.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Remember to post your attempt at the script next time please.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```python
import re
import subprocess

# Exec the command and get the output
output = subprocess.getoutput('sudo rsync -avzh --stats /etc /home /usr /mnt/BigMac/BigMac/PiBackups/PiZero')

# Should do some error handling here, if needed. output can be stderr

# Match total file size, capture it into group 1
# Line from start to end with non-greedy anything before "bytes" captured
# It could be more accurate like (\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]) but I don't know exact possible formats
total_size = re.search(r'^Total file size: (.*?) bytes$', output, re.MULTILINE).group(1)

# Match total bytes, capture it into group 1, similarly as above
total_bytes = re.search(r'^Total bytes sent: (.*?)$', output, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
```